# Reading enterprise library logs using logstash

Tags: logstash

I have the following log file for which i want the logstash could parse out the necessary information.

What are the filter conditions for the conf file ?

```
Timestamp: 9/23/2015 12:47:25 PM Message: HandlingInstanceID: 76dd3c9f-1476-4eaf-ac8c-0f56d9c81267 An exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred and was caught.

09/23/2015 05:47:24 Type : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException, System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Message : Error in User.SetProfile Source : System.Web.Services Help link :  Actor :  Code : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Detail : System.Xml.XmlElement Lang : en-US Node :  Role :  SubCode :  Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal TargetSite : System.Object[] ReadResponse(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage, System.Net.WebResponse, System.IO.Stream, Boolean) HResult :
-2146233087 Stack Trace : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Additional Info:

MachineName : XXXXXXXXTimeStamp : 9/23/2015 12:47:25 PM
FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral,

PublicKeyToken=null
AppDomainName : xxxxxxxx
ThreadIdentity : 
WindowsIdentity : XXXXXXXXX
Category: IIONLogging

```
          Priority: 0
```

EventId: 100
Severity: Error

```
          Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling
```

Machine: XXXXXXXXX
App Domain: xxxxxxxxxxxx

```
          ProcessId: xxxx
```

Process Name: xxxxxxx

```
          Thread Name:
```

Win32 ThreadId:5096

```
          Extended Properties: User Creation/Updation : Ebus Agent ID - xxxxxx
```

Company ID - 111
Parent Company ID - 111
Create BY CPM Profile ID - 11111111

The above log is repeated several times.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you need a logstash filter? Please clarify what your actual problem is.

Comment: Yes.. i wanted the filter conditions that could parse the enterprise library log files of the above format.